Question on the exact largest minimum angle
Could anyone help find the EXACT largest minimum angle between any pair of lines among 5 lines passing through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Additionally, what is the exact largest minimum angle between any pair of lines among 7 lines passing through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$?
Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Equivalently, you want to place $2n$ points in opposite pairs on the unit sphere, maximizing the minimum distance between any two points, for $n=5$ or $n=7$.  Without the constraint of opposite pairs, this problem is discussed at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088788/placing-n-points-on-a-sphere, which contains various useful links.  From that discussion I suspect that there is no closed formula for $n=5$ or $n=7$.

@NeilStrickland  Thank you for your comment and for the link, but aren't both the quantity in the minimum of Thompson's problem and the quantity in the minimum of Smale's problem different from that in this question? Thanks.

You are asking about real projective codes. The second table here provides the angles you seek: https://cohn.mit.edu/spherical-codes/

@DustinG.Mixon Thank you for your answer. What does minimal polynomial in projective code mean? and is there any exact value of the angle rather than an estimate? Thanks!

@Donna - The cosine of the minimal angle is the root of a polynomial with integer coefficients. The polynomial of lowest degree with this property is called the minimal polynomial. For example, in the case of 5 lines in 3 dimensions, the cosine of the minimum angle is a root of $5x^2-1$, i.e., $\cos\theta\in{\pm1/\sqrt{5}}$. Comparing with the numerical approximation given in the table, it follows that $\cos\theta=1/\sqrt{5}$.

@DustinG.Mixon  Thank you for your comment. How  about the asymptotic upper bound for the minimum angle between any pair of lines among $n$ lines in $\mathbb{R}^d$? Thank you!

@Don - what do you mean by asymptotic? what are you fixing, and what are you sending to infinity?

@Don - if you fix d, then by compactness, the minimum angle goes to zero as n goes to infinity

@DustinG.Mixon  Thanks. But how about the most updated or best estimational upper bound for the minimum angle between any pair of lines among $n$ lines in $\mathbb{R}^d$? Thank you!

TL, DR: We show that with five axes the angle will satisfy
$63°26'05''<\theta<65°31'49''.\tag{*}$
*Though this analysis does not prove it, the lower bound turns out to be sharp (apart from rounding to the nearest second). See the second table in https://cohn.mit.edu/spherical-codes/.
The complexity of the problem is well illustrated by the unconstrained problem of maximizing the distance between ten points on a sphere. Instead of a basally bicapped square antiprism as one might expect, the solution is the low-symmetry figure indicated in the figure below from the referenced site:

Compared with the bicapped antiprism, one cap has been squeezed out and its vertex forced into what would have been the opposing basal layer. We should assume that a similar solution would be required for the constrained case where five or seven pairs of points on a sphere must be antipodally located.
That being so, we can bound the angle for five pairs of antipodal points by elementary means, with a range of less than 3° between the bounds.
For the lower bound, we consider the case of six pairs of antipodal points, thus twelve points in all. In this case we can set the axes to match the six fivefold axes of the regular icosahedron, and we know that this must be optimal for six antipodal pairs (and for the unconstrained Tammes problem with twelve points) because all faces of the polyhedron are triangular and all edges are congruent. The edges of a regular icosahedron are well known to intercept arcs measuring $\arctan(2)$ on the circumsctibed sphere, giving the lower bound
$\theta\ge\arctan(2)>63°26'05''.$
The seconds are rounded downwards for the lower bound. (As noted in the TL, DR this bound turns out to be sharp with more sophisticated analysis. See https://cohn.mit.edu/spherical-codes/.)
For the upper bound we consider a less constrained case with ten points on the sphere, requiring only that at least one pair be antipodal. This is whete the basally bicapped square antiprism comes into play, with its $D_{4d}$ symmetry. Given this symmetry there are just three distinct distances on the convex hull: the lateral edges of the antiprism, the basal edges where the antiprism meets the capping pyramids, and the lateral edges of the pyramids. An optimal arrangement would requure two of these lengths to be equal with the third one longer; the only case that works is to equate the two sets of lateral edges.
We then draw the projections of the lateral edges on the sphere and triangulate the resulting rhombi by drawing in the basal edges. With the two sets of lateral edges equated and the improper eightfold symmetry axis, this divides the sphere into sixteen congruent isosceles triangles having base angles of 67°30' and apex angles of 90°. Using the spherical laws of cosines we can solve for the legs of these triangles, which correspond to the equated edges of the bicapped antiprism. The upper bound thereby obtained is
$\theta\le\arccos(\sqrt2-1)<65°31'49''$
with the seconds rounded up.

Thank you for your answer. What does minimal polynomial in projective code mean? and could you find the exact value of $\theta$ rather than an estimate?? Thanks!

As I state, references given in the answer actually show the lower bound is exact. (It was to my surprise.)

How many among the 10 angles between pairs of the 5 lines of the maximiser are equal to  $\theta$ ?

All of them. Think of five of the six fivefold axes of the regular icosahedron.

I see,  this is what you said about the largest minimum angle for 5 lines  being  actually equal to the lower bound (=the  largest minimum angle for 6 lines).

Why ddid you say "lower bound" if it is EXACT value? Which reference do you refer to? and what is the EXACT value of the largest minimum angle? Thanks.

Again the second table in the link gives vest known results and indicates which are rigorously known, the latter including the case of five antipodal pairs of points in tgree-dimensional space. I do not understand why you fo not just look the link up.

@OscarLanzi Thank you for your comment. What are the directional vectors of the lines that achieve the maximal minimum angle between them? Thank you!
